# Cardinality of set of all nonempty open interval with rational endpoint is same as the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

**My attempt:**

Define the collection of set  $\mathcal{I}:=\{(a,b):a,b\in\mathbb{Q},a<b\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, $\mathcal{I}\subset\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$, so there is injective function, namely indentity function $id:\mathcal{I}\to\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$. We also know that $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\sim\mathbb{Q}\sim\mathbb{N}$, so $|\mathcal{I}|\leqslant d$

It's sufficient to find injective $g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathcal{I}$ to claim $d\leqslant|\mathcal{I}|$.

\begin{align}
g:\mathbb{N}&\to\mathcal{I}\\
n&\mapsto (n,n+1)
\end{align}

Hence, $|\mathcal{I}|=d$

**Is this seems to be correct? Please leave a comment either right or wrong.**

Comment: What is meant by $d$?

Comment: @K.Jiang denumerable. $|\mathbb{N}|=d$

Comment: I see. Strictly speaking, it is not true that $\mathcal{I} \subseteq \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$. The former consists of *intervals* on the real line, while the latter consists of pairs of numbers.

Comment: @K.Jiang Thank you for your reply. how can I refine it, or can I just say that interpret the ordered pair $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$$ with $a<b$ as interval?

Comment: However, this is not a huge problem since you can define a map $f: \mathcal{I} \to \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ given by $f ((a, b)) = a \times b$. To show $\mathcal{I}$ is countable, you just need to show that $f$ is injective (given you have an injection $g: \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{N}$).

Comment: To show $\mathcal{I}$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N}$, you would further need to show that $\mathcal{I}$ is infinite. That should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: @K.Jiang Thank you for your reply. If defined as $a\times b$ it becomes a real number and is no longer an element in $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$, which may not be consistent. 

you may also would like to see my another post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4880057/collection-of-all-open-sets-in-mathbbr-has-the-same-cardinality-as-mathbb

Comment: If $(a, b) \in \mathcal{I}$, then by definition $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$, and by definition $a \times b \in \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$. (Note that "$\times$" here denotes the Cartesian product, not the arithmetic product.)

Comment: I think there is more wrong than right with this.  1) $(a,b)$ is not an ordered pair (although it has the exact same notation.  Best to use notation $\langle a,b\rangle= \{x\in \mathbb R| a<b\}$.  2) so $\mathcal I = \{\langle a,b\rangle| a,b \in \mathbb Q\}$.  What you need to do is a way to map a single interval $\langle a,b\rangle$ to a single natural number.

Comment: If you use a *bi*jection from $\mathcal I\to \mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q$ that will tell you that $|\mathcal I| = |\mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q|$ and you won't need to find the injection the other way.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you for your reply. I can't think of any bijection $\mathcal{I}\to\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ in this specific form

Comment: I was thinking of $(a,b)=\{x| a< x < b\}$ mapping to $(a,b)= \{a\}\times \{b\}$ (sorry about the mixed notation.  I'm really not sure what the convention for dealing with it is) but then I realized this isn't exactly a bijection as the image is actually $\{(a,b)\in \mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q| a< b\}\subsetneq \mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q$.  But it's easily worked around but knowing that $|\mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q|= |\mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q^{+}\setminus\{0\}|$ and we can map the interval $(a,b)$ to the ordered pair $(a, b-a)$ and that would be a bijection.

Comment: We know $|\mathbb N| = |\mathbb Q| = |\mathbb Q^+| = |\text{any countable set}| = |\text{any other countable set minus any finite set}|$ and we know that if $A$ and $B$ are countable then $A\times B$ is countable.  So... we can find a bijection from $\{(a,b)=\{x|a<x<b\}|a,b\in \mathbb Q\} \to \mathbb Q\times {\mathbb Q^+\setminus{0}}$ via $(a,b)\to a\times(b-a)$.  Thus $|\{(a,b)\}|=|Q\times {\mathbb Q^+\setminus{0}}|= |\mathbb N|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious what I am going to say but: two non-empty intervals $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ coincide if and only if $a=c$ and $b=d$. In particular, this is true if $a,b,c,d$ are rational numbers. Because of that, the function

$$f:\{(a,b)\neq\emptyset:(a,b)\textrm{ interval, }a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}\to\{\langle a,b\rangle:\langle a,b\rangle\textrm{ ordered pair with }a\leq b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$$
is a bijection. The right-hand-side has size, at most, $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$. But the cardinality of $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$, so we have finished.