collection of all open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$
This is a succesive question from the following post Cardinality of set of all nonempty open interval with rational endpoint is same as the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$
$$\mathcal{I}:=\{(a,b):a,b\in\mathbb{Q},a<b\}$$
Let $\mathcal{O}$ denote the collection of all countable unions of open intervals in
$\mathcal{I}$
$$\mathcal{O}:=\{U\subset\mathbb{R}:U=\bigcup^{\infty}_{j=1} I_j, I_j\in\mathcal{I}\}$$
What is the cardinality of $\mathcal{O}$?

Below is the Lecturer Given Solution
Each set in $\mathcal{O}$ is a countable (finite or denumerable) union of elements
of $\mathcal{I}$. So each element of $\mathcal{O}$ corresponds to a finite or denumerable subset
$\{\mathcal{I}_{i1}
, \mathcal{I}_{i2}
, . . . \}$ of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{I})$, where we may assume that intervals in this listing
are not repeated. Thus $\mathcal{O}$ has the same cardinality as $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{I})$. Since the cardinality of $\mathcal{I}$ is $d$, $\mathcal{O}$ has cardinality $2^d = \mathfrak{c}=
|\mathbb{R}|$
Some questions for the solution
Question 1
I know that every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ can be uniquely written as a disjoint union of open intervals, however, $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{I})$ is the power set of all rational endpoints intervals, what if the open set in $\mathcal{O}$ with the irrational endpoint.
Question 2
Let open set $U,V\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $U\neq V$, every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ can be uniquely written as disjoint union of open interval, then can we conclude that $\{n:I_n\subset U\}\neq\{m:I_m\subset V\}$
Appreciate for any solution and comment.

Ad 1. We can reach each irrational point by rational estimations and in that way construct countable family wich Union is set is that interval wich you look
Ad 2. Consider $ U \setminus V $

To answer your question (1): you can show that for any $a < b \in \mathbb{R}$, there is a $c \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $a < c < b$. For this reason, any open set $O \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ can be expressed as a union of intervals of the form $(p, q)$, where $p < q \in \mathbb{Q}$.

To answer your question (2): suppose WLOG that $U$ contains an element $x$ that is not contained in $V$. Since $U$ is open, it must contain an interval $(p_x, q_x)$ with $p_x < q_x \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x \in (p_x, q_x) \subseteq U$. Let the "index" of this interval be $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Note that $k \in {n | I_n \subseteq U} - {m | I_m \subseteq V}$.

@K.Jiang Thank you for your reply. Yeah, I know that the rational is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and any irrational number can be a limit designated to have a convergent sequence of rational numbers. However, I cannot convince myself that an open set has such form $(\pi,4)$ ....... Oh!!!, we could have the disjoint union of open sets whose left entries $(\cdot, m)$ keep taking the terms in such convergent rational sequence.

@LJNG You have the right idea. If you give me any $x \in (\pi, 4)$, by the density of rationals, I can always find you $y \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\pi < y < x$, such that $x \in (y, 4) \subseteq (\pi, 4)$, and $(y, 4)$ is an element of $\mathcal{I}$.

@K.Jiang Thanks for Q2 reply, Should the ${n:I_n\subset U}$ and ${m:I_m\subset V}$ have the same cardinality ? these are the set of indexing elements, so they have the same size but are actually "different"

@LJNG They have the same cardinality if $U, V$ are both non-empty (in which case that cardinality is equal to the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$), as you can check. If one of $U, V$ is the empty set, then the cardinality of the corresponding index set is obviously $0$.

@K.Jiang Thank you so much, you saved my life today. One last question, in your reply  said that I have the right idea comment. I am thinking about if I would like to have countable disjoint union of open interval to represent $(\pi, 4)$, we may have $\ldots\cup(\cdot,a)\cup(a,4)$, where $a$ has to be an rational. How do we think of that missing $a$ not in any of intervals that we creat?

For example, the open set $(0, 1)$ can be expressed as the union of the singleton ${(0, 1)}$ or as the union of $\left{ \left( 0, \frac{2}{3} \right), \left( \frac{1}{3}, 1 \right) \right}$.

@K.Jiang Thanks for clearing my mind. So for the example $(\pi,4)$ in the context of having a countable union of rational endpoints open interval representation, we cannot have those open intervals to be disjoint.  it must be disjoint in the sense that $(\pi,4)$ itself is an open interval.

Correct. Those intervals cannot all be disjoint because $(\pi, 4)$ is an open interval. I'm not sure if you've studied connectedness, but you can easily show why using the fact that intervals are connected.

This is besides the point, but I believe there is a part missing from the lecturer's solution, which is to show that the cardinality of $\mathcal{O}$ is at least that of $\mathbb{R}$ (the given proof only shows that the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ is not smaller than that of $\mathcal{O}$). But this is trivial, since the collection ${(x, x + 1) | x \in (0, 1)} \subseteq \mathcal{O}$ of open sets already has the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$.

Edit: "I know that every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ can be uniquely written as a disjoint union of open intervals"... this is true when we allow general intervals but becomes irrelevant when we are restricted to intervals with rational endpoints: it may be impossible to express an open set as a disjoint union of such intervals, as you've shown with the example $(\pi, 4)$.

Okay, for Question 1,
you have already shown that the set $\mathcal{I}$ with rational endpoints is countable using this set you defined the set $\mathcal{O}$, which is similar to the power set of the set $\mathcal{I}$. Now I am assuming that you want to know, what if the set $\mathcal{I}$ is a set of all open intervals with irrational endpoints, Correct me if I am wrong. So,
If  $~~\mathcal{I}=\{(a,b):a,b\in\mathbb{I},a<b\}$ , where $\mathbb{I}$ is the set of all irrational numbers. Now consider $\delta \in \mathbb{I}$ and $\delta >0$.
Let $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, then $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\in \mathcal{I}$.
Since there is an uncountably infinite choice of such $\delta$ we can say that $\mathcal{I}$ is an uncountable set. Now you can show as you have shown before that the set $\mathcal{O}$ constructed with this set $\mathcal{I}$ is similar to $\mathcal{P(I)}$ which is of cardinality $2^c$. And I think you already got the answer to your second question in the comment section.
